# Subtracting DataFrames resulting in unexpected numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to subtract one data frame from another which all results should result in a 0 or blank based on the data in each my current excel files but will result in 0, 1, 2, or blank in the future. While some do result in a 0 or blank I'm also getting a -1 and 1. Any help that can be provided will be appreciated.

The two Excel sheets are identical except for number changes in second column.

Example

```
ExternalId TotalInteractions
name1            1
name2            2
name3            2
name4            1
```

Both sheets will look like the example and the output will look the same. I just need the difference between the two sheets

```
def GCList():
    df1 = pd.read_excel('NewInter.xlsx')
    df2 = pd.read_excel('PrevInter.xlsx')

    df3 = df1['ExternalId']
    df4 = df1['TotalInteractions']
    df5 = df2['TotalInteractions']
    df6 = df4.sub(df5)
    frames = (df3, df6)
    df = pd.concat(frames, axis = 1)


    df.to_excel('GCList.xlsx')


GCList()
```

I managed to create a partial answer to getting the unexpected numbers. My problem now is that NewInter has more names than PrevInter does. Which results in a blank in TotalInteractions next to the new ExternalId. Any idea how to make it if it there is a blank to accept the value from NewInter?

```
def GCList():
    df1 = pd.read_excel('NewInter.xlsx')
    df2 = pd.read_excel('PrevInter.xlsx')

    
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'ExternalId', how = 'outer')
    df4 = df3['TotalInteractions_x']
    df5 = df3['TotalInteractions_y']
    df6 = df3['ExternalId']
    df7 = df4 - df5
    frames = [df6,df7]
    df = pd.concat(frames, axis = 1)
    df.to_excel('GCList.xlsx')


GCList()
```

Comment: Please provide sample data for both dataframes and expected output based on that.

Comment: Added in a quick example. Apologies, new to programming and stackoverflow

Comment: Please add proper input of both frames and the output you expect to see.

Comment: The frames are identical except for numbers in the second column. The input numbers never go higher than 2 and never go lower than 1. The output should look exactly like the input sheets but with the difference between the second columns

Comment: Because of NewInt is a growing list do I need to map it in someway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issues. First part needed to be merged in order for the subtraction to work as the dataframes are not the same size. Also had to add in fill_value = 0 so it would take information from the new file.

```
def GCList():
    df1 = pd.read_excel('NewInter.xlsx')
    df2 = pd.read_excel('PrevInter.xlsx')

    
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'ExternalId', how = 'outer')
    df4 = df3['TotalInteractions_x']
    df5 = df3['TotalInteractions_y']
    df6 = df3['ExternalId']
    df7 = df4.sub(df5, fill_value = 0)
    frames = [df6,df7]
    df = pd.concat(frames, axis = 1)
    df.to_excel('GCList.xlsx')


GCList()
```